# How to change url in extjs4 based on per page render?

Tags: url, extjs, url-routing, extjs-mvc, extjs4.2

I am working in ExtJs4.I am getting stuck at a point where I have to **change my url** like E://demoProj/index.html to E://demoProj/index.html#firstpage or E://demoProj/index.html#secondpage based on per page(view) in extjs4.I trid a lot but not yet solved it.How can I solve this problem? 
Please give me some guideline.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're asking is how to change the anchor is the address bar, here's how:

```
window.location.hash = 'firstpage';
```

If your question is more about how to keep track of the view count, you'll need some sort of storage mecanism. If you restrict yourself to the client-side, [cookies](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#) may be a solution.

Example:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var cookies = Ext.util.Cookies,
        // accounting for first time (undefined), and casting to int
        currentViewCount = +cookies.get('viewCount') || 0;

    // update view count
    cookies.set('viewCount', currentViewCount + 1);

    window.location.hash = 'page' + currentViewCount;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using card layout and Menus, here is what you could do :

**In your viewport**

```
var APP_CARD_ITEMS_MAP = new Ext.util.HashMap();
APP_CARD_ITEMS_MAP.add('home', 0);
APP_CARD_ITEMS_MAP.add('page1', 1);
APP_CARD_ITEMS_MAP.add('page2', 2);

Ext.define('AM.view.Viewport' ,{
extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
id:'myviewport',
requires:[
          'APP.view.*'    
          ], 
items: [{
        xtype:'panel',
        items:[     
               {
                xtype:'panel',
                items: [                
                      {
                        xtype:'BodyPanel',
                        id:'bodypanel' 
                      } 
                    ]
              }
             ]
             ...........
```

Create a container(here bodypanel) and include all your pages over their.On click you can change the url and desired page using :

```
window.location.hash = '#'+ menu.itemId;
Ext.getCmp('bodypanel').getLayout().setActiveItem(1);
```

**In your BodyPanel**

```
  Ext.define('AM.view.BodyPanel',{
  extend:'Ext.Container', 
  alias:'widget.BodyPanel',
  xtype:'bodypanel',
  requires:[''],  //your views
  fullscreen:true,
  layout: 'card',
  activeItem:0,   
  listeners:{
      afterrender:function(){
         var hashedUrl = window.location.hash; 
            if(hashedUrl && hashedUrl.indexOf(":")==-1){
                hashedUrl = hashedUrl.substring(1, hashedUrl.length);
                var activeItem = APP_CARD_ITEMS_MAP.get(hashedUrl);
                Ext.getCmp('bodypanel').getLayout().setActiveItem(activeItem);
            }   
      }
  },
  items : [{
              xtype: 'page1',                         
                  id:'page1',
                  x:200
            },{
                  xtype: 'page2',
                  id:'page2',
                  x:200
            },
          ]
  .............
```